# search for a revision in tig

Tags: git, tig

I'm a big fan of tig http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig

Using "/" like in vim we can search for comit with /

I'm looking for to get a specific hashtag e.g 2f12bcc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just like in vim use

:hashtag

e.g:

```
 :2f12bcc
```

see more on the official documentation [1]

[1] http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html#prompt